# mod_rewrite is enabled, .htaccess file is ok, but requests are not going through index.php

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, apache2

I've just installed ubuntu-server_6.04.2_LTS, after the fresh installation I've enabled mod_rewrite, it's showing in phpinfo()
my .htaccess file is OK 
but, still requests are not going through index.php
[image]

Comment: What type of error is generated or how is it failing? Check error logs and the answer Alex gave. If you are not using rewirteBase in htaccess check your base_url in config.php.

Comment: no error, but I need to type domain.tld/ci/index.php/controller/method
if index.php is not described in the URL, CodeIniter error 404 is not shown, default apache error 404 page is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if for that specific directory (root folder of your project), apache is configured to allow overriding through .htaccess.

If you want to allow such override, the directives found in apache.conf or the specific settings for your virtual host should look like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```